# How to create dynamic webpage with custom name?

Tags: php

I have looked around and attempted my own research on this topic but to no avail just yet.

I have a dynamic webpage set up to look for a ID from a database to retrieve elements required. This results in of course the web page looking like `www.site.com/page?id=1`

My desired outcome would be like a title for this page to be called.
Such as say I had a fruit product it and user went to my site and went to the address `/fruit` it would it would be the content of ?id=1 just as an example.

I have seen this used on many a site but not sure how this is programmed or works. Is this something to do with a htaccess document?

Thanks in advance. Appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this has been asked and answered many times, I know many people find it difficult to search for this since there are so many common "noise" words related to it. For that reason, I believe it's worth answering again.

If you're using Apache as your webserver (which I'm assuming you are since you mention `.htaccess`), what you're looking for to create those "clean URLs" is [`mod_rewrite`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), which takes a set of rules and rewrites the URL requested by the browser to another path or script.

You would typically enable this in your Apache config or in `.htaccess`, and in a simple form (a one-to-one mapping) at it would look something like this (provided `mod_rewrite` is installed):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^fruit$ index.php?type=1 [L]
```

Now obviously that doesn't scale well if you have a bunch of dynamic pages you want to create, so what you can do is tell all pages that aren't a really file or directory to be passed to a file for processing, like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

In this case we're rewriting any request that doesn't resolve to a real file or directory to index.php, and then using the "last" flag `[L]` to stop processing other rules.  Then in our PHP script, we can access the virtual path (in this case `/fruit`) by using `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` and doing whatever conditional logic we want with that. If you don't get anything in that variable, ensure that the [`AcceptPathInfo On`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo) directive is set in your Apache config or `.htaccess`.

A way to test the basic concept/logic without having any rewrite rules would be to use a URL like `https://example.com/index.php/fruit`. You'll then see that in index.php `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` will contain the string `/fruit`. You can rewrite URLs to files in other directories, chain rewrite rules, redirect the browser to other URLs, or even edit environment variables.

There are many good tutorials around using `mod_rewrite` for clean URLs, so I won't attempt to cover all the nuances here. Just know that it's a very powerful tool, but it's also pretty easy to break your rules if you aren't very comfortable with regular expressions or get lost in the many rules that are commonly in a configuration.

Note that if this is an existing site, you'll also want to use `mod_rewrite` or `mod_redirect` to redirect the old URLs to the new ones so they don't break (and for the benefit of having a single URL for search rankings).